# Apache on Centos doesn't recognize gmp extension

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, php7

I have this error in running a webapp on a Centos 7, PHP 7.2 server:

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function gmp_init() in ... a.php on line 2**

If I call it from cmd line it works:

b:3

Code:

```
<?php
$b = gmp_init( 3, 16 );
echo "b:" . $b;
?>
```

How can I tell apache to load the extension?

thanks

Comment: Do you have php-gmp installed? Check php.ini to see if you have `extension=php_gmp.so`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing "php-gmp" on your server using Yum like #yum install *php-gmp*. It will pull all the 
available php-gmp version from the repo. Then enable it in your php.ini file like "extension=php_gmp.so".